# why i can not resize a button in javafx with css

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to resize a button but it doesn't work.

the css file is linked to file properly. (the color of button changes)

```java
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    Button btn = new Button("s");
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("Style.css");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

### css file

```css
.button {
  -fx-width: 250px;
  -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

also i cannot set spacing for vbox.(it dosent work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for setting width of all buttons:

```
.button {
    -fx-min-width: 20px;
    -fx-max-width: 20px;
    -fx-pref-width: 20px;
}
```

Choose the property you want to set (*max*, *min*, *pref*, or all of them).
Its the same for *height*, just replace *width* with *height*.
To set spacing for VBox, according to [this Oracle post](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/style_css.htm) you can do it using:

```
.vbox {
    -fx-spacing: 10;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that for the last snippet to work the styleclass needs to be added manually. By default `VBox` does not feature any styleclasses...